# POST 500 (Internal Server Error) Node.js Backend

Tags: node.js, json, server, undefined, backend

I hope you're all doing well.

I tried trouble shooting as Ms. Laurence Cherone told me and it seems the compiler doesn't go through the entire function it stops at this line :

```
const exercise=JSON.parse(req.body.exercise);
```

Here is the entire function I don't think I am doing anything wrong :

```
create:(req,res)=>{
        console.log("Test1");
        
        console.log("Test1bis");
        const exercise=JSON.parse(req.body.exercise);
        delete exercise._id;
        console.log("Test2")
        const exerciseB = new Exercise({
            ...exercise,
            image:`${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/images/exercise/${req.file.filename}`,
            video:`${req.protocole}://${req.get('host')}/videos/exercise/${req.file.filename}`
        })
        console.log("Test3")

        exerciseB.save((err,exercise)=>{
            if(err){
                console.log("C'est le 2eme err");
                return res.status(500).json({
                    status:500,
                    message:err.message
                })
            }
            console.log("Ca arrive jusqu'au 200");
            return res.status(200).json({
                status:200,
                message:"Exercise Created Successfully !"
            })
        })
    }
```

And this is what I get  on my terminal (You will notice that not all the console.log are printing only the 2 first ones) :
[image]

After looking further into the code I tried launching the request on postman and got this :

[image]

Meaning that I am doing a JSON.parse(undefined) at the line :

```
const exercise=JSON.parse(req.body.exercise);
```

but I still don't know how to fix it. I tried replacing that line with:

```
const exercise=JSON.parse(req.body);
```

But got no luck there eather.

Comment: all i can see are the JSON logs. where is the error stack?

Comment: I am sorry, this might sound dumb but where can I find the error stack ?

Comment: You see the logs in whatever terminal you're running the server in

Comment: The only terminal I am using is the Visual Studio Code terminal. I am adding it in the question above in case that is what you mean

Comment: a 500 is not specific to just the database it could be other code. do some debugging in the error handler instead of just outputting `POST /exercises/create 500 24.235ms - 55` as that's not a useful error message, id be interested to know what's underneath that line?

Comment: Could you just have a try-catch over some parts of your code and check if it catches something?

Comment: Seems that `req.body.exercise` is undefined which makes sense since your request JSON body doesn't contain an `exercise` property. Why are you trying to parse JSON from the request anyway? Assuming you're using `app.use(express.json())` (see https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#express.json), then `req.body` should contain the already parsed JSON from the request (an object with `name`, `video` and `image` properties)

Comment: Ok so there is no need to parse the data a simple ...req.body would do ?